# How can I POST data using API from REACTJS?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, reactjs, react-native

This is my react code here I want to POST Data using postPoll API and update polls state but I am not understand how can do that.
please help..! please help..!please help..!please help..!please help..!please help..!please help..! at line number 33, 34 ( handalchange )

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Poll from "react-polls";
import "../../styles.css";
import { isAutheticated } from "../../auth/helper/index";
import { getPolls, postPoll } from "../helper/coreapicalls";
import axios from "axios";
import { API } from "../../backend";

const MainPoll = () => {
  const userId = isAutheticated() && isAutheticated().user._id;
  const [polls, setPoll] = useState([]);
  const [error, seterror] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadPoll();
  }, []);

  const loadPoll = () => {
    getPolls().then((data) => {
      if (data.error) {
        seterror(data.error);
      } else {
        setPoll(data);
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  };

  // Handling user vote
  // Increments the votes count of answer when the user votes
  const handalchange = async (pollId, userId, answer) => {
    console.log(pollId); // getting
    console.log(userId); // getting
    console.log(answer); // getting
    await axios.post(`${API}/vote/${pollId}`, userId, answer);
    // postPoll(pollId, { userId, vote }).then(() => {
    //   loadPoll();
    // });
  };

  return (
    <div className="">
      <div className="container my-5">
        <h1 className="blog_heading my-3">Poll's of the Day</h1>
        <div className="row">
          {polls.reverse().map((poll, index) => (
            <div className="col-lg-4 col-12 poll_border" key={index}>
              <Poll
                noStorage
                question={poll.question}
                answers={Object.keys(poll.options).map((key) => {
                  return {
                    option: key,
                    votes: poll.options[key].length,
                  };
                })}
                onVote={
                  (answer) =>
                    handalchange(poll._id, userId, answer, console.log(answer)) // getting vote
                }
                className="mb-2"
              />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MainPoll;
```

this is my frontend-[image: new error]
POSTMAN - request = > [image]

and here is my backend API -

```
// post
export const postPoll = (pollId, post) => {
  return fetch(`${API}/vote/${pollId}`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(post),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what object does `onVote` event from `Poll` component pass. But if it's vote object, that's required in postPoll method as second arguement, than:

1. function in onVote event should pass poll.id from this component and vote object from `Vote` component `onVote` event itself:

```
                onVote={(vote) => handalchange(poll.id, vote)}
```

2. handalchange should fire postPoll api method with these arguements and load updated poll data on success:

```
const handalchange = (pollId, vote) => {
    postPoll(pollId, vote).then(() => {
        loadPoll();
    });
}
```

Comment: hi ..! @Alexander I am getting undefined while console.log(vote); on handalchange please check . I have updated my code ..! see

Comment: check what's in your `vote` object from `onVote` event argument first. try to console.log second argument of handalchange without destructuring like that `const handalchange = async (pollId, vote) => {
    console.log(pollId);
    console.log(vote);
}`

Comment: I guess if your api requires not only post object in body, but something like `{post: post, userId: userId}` - you could just remove destructuring and it should work. You already have `userId` from 10 line `const userId = isAutheticated() && isAutheticated().user._id;`

Comment: hi,@Alexander my API requirement is - pollId , userId, answer .                                            answer - is options which we are choosing ...! so what to do now..?

Comment: please help..!  I'm still confused

Comment: hello,@Alexander I have updated my code..! please check

Comment: your last error is that you pass `answer` as third argument in `axios.post` method. you can just wrap second and third arguments into single object like that `axios.post(\`${API}/vote/${pollId}\`, {userId, answer});`

please, ask a new question instead of editing this next time :)
it's very inconvenient to answer this way